# Critical section in service, multithreaded service

Tags: multithreading, delphi, service

I developed a service application which is collecting JPEG data from some equipment.
Number of remote devices varies from 1 up to 20.

After service start it creates a number of threads=current number of remote devices.

Every thread is writing into global array of records.

Record:

```
type
TDevice=record
  devName:string;
  ms:TMemoryStream;
end;

Devices:array of TDevice;

CS:TCriticalSection;
```

Threads creation

```
cs:=TCriticalsection.Create;

for i := 0 to device_list_names.Count-1 do
  begin
    packs[i].ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    arr_CT[i]:=TClientThread.Create(false,device_list_ip.Strings[i],
      cs,packs[i].ms);

    arr_CT[i].FreeOnTerminate:=false;
    arr_CT[i].Priority:=tpLower;
  end;
```

Thread destroing

```
for i := 0 to length(arr_CT)-1 do
  begin
    arr_CT[i].Terminate;
    arr_CT[i].waitfor;
    arr_CT[i].free;
  end;
```

Thread code

```
type
  TClientThread = class(TThread)
 private
   imconnected:boolean;
   FLock:TCriticalSection;
   FAddress:string;
   LogPath:string;
   tcpcli:TIdTCPClient;
   Fms:TMemoryStream;
   procedure CreateSocket;
   procedure GetImageStreamTCP;
 protected
   procedure Execute;override;
 public
   constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean;const Address:string;
    var ALock:TCriticalSection; var Ams:TMemoryStream);
 end;

const
  socketport:integer=12340;

implementation

uses GlobalVariables, superlog;

constructor TClientThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean;const Address:string;
  var ALock:TCriticalSection; var Ams:TMemoryStream);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FLock:=ALock;
  Fms:=Ams;
  FAddress:=Address;

  imconnected:=false;

  LogPath:='E:\NetView07\Logs\'+FAddress+'_'+
    FormatDateTime('dd-mm-yyyy',now)+'.log';

  posttolog(LogPath,'E:\NetView07\Logs\_'+
            FormatDateTime('dd-mm-yyyy',now)+'.log');

  PostToLog('Thread '+FAddress+' started',Logpath);
end;

procedure TClientThread.CreateSocket;
begin
  tcpcli:=TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  tcpcli.Host:=FAddress;
  tcpcli.Port:=socketport;
  tcpcli.ReadTimeout:=3000;
end;

procedure TClientThread.GetImageStreamTCP;
begin
  try
    try
      if not imconnected then
        begin
          tcpcli.Connect;
          imconnected:=true;
        end;
      Flock.Enter;
      Fms.Clear;
      tcpcli.IOHandler.WriteLn('grab');
      tcpcli.IOHandler.ReadStream(Fms, -1);
    except on e:exception do
      begin
        posttolog('Error on receive stream('+FAddress+'): ' + e.Message,LogPath);
        imconnected:=false;
        try
          tcpcli.Disconnect;
        except on e:Exception do
        end;
        posttolog('imconnected=false',LogPath);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FLock.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TClientThread.Execute;
begin
  CreateSocket;

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    GetImageStreamTCP;
    Sleep(200);
  end;
  try
    tcpcli.Disconnect;
  Except on e:Exception do
  end;
  FreeAndNil(tcpcli);

  posttolog(FAddress+' terminated.',LogPath);
end;
```

The problem is that sometimes the service hangs without any errors.
I think that the problem is in CriticalSection, because if i will fill my code with enough logging  then last logs entries will be before Flock.Enter.

Could You tell me what i'm doing wrong?

I'm sorry if i created a duplicate of question. I tried to find the same like questions, but no results.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but the resource acquisition in a try finally must be immediately before the try. You call FLock.Enter in the wrong place. As for the lock, what is it protecting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank You for comment. Of course it need to be 'Flock.Enter try try except on e:exception do end finally Flock.Leave end'. My idea was to protect with Lock access to array of records (such like Devices[i].ms). Am i correct?

Comment: If each thread accesses its own stream, why do you need to lock. Locks are for accessing a shared resource.

Comment: That critical section is wrong. Each TDevice would have to use own critical section. This one locks whole Devices array. And yes, it is useless because the stream is not shared between threads. You can also eliminate that CreateSuspended from Create procedure, it is useless there. You should put whole code in Execute into try/except to catch any unwanted exception.

Comment: Thank You for comments, colleagues. I understand that if i'm only writing into array of TDevices then i dont need Flock. But i forgot to post that clients can connect to this service via LAN and get memorystream data stored in Devices[i].ms. So that was the reason to use CriticalSection. If one thread is writing into Devices[1].ms (f.e.) and another thread is reading Devices[1].ms at the same time then i will receive an Exception. Am i correct?   @smooty86, you think that i need to create something like TDevice=record dcs:TCriticalSection; ms:TMemoryStream end;?

Comment: Well, if it was locked then the problem is probably not there. But you locked whole array which is wrong. The problem might be somewhere else. See my answer. Use class instead.

Comment: You need a one to one mapping between lock instances and shared resources. Each stream is shared between reader and writer. So, each stream needs to have its own lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should use construction like this**

```
type
  TDevice = class
  protected
    FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
    FDevName: string;
    Fms: TMemoryStream;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Lock;
    procedure Unlock;

    property DevName: string read FDevName write FDevName;
    property ms: TMemoryStream read Fms write Fms;
  end;

...

constructor TDevice.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
  Fms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

destructor TDevice.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FCriticalSection);
  FreeAndNil(Fms);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TDevice.Lock;
begin
  FCriticalSection.Enter;
end;

procedure TDevice.Unlock;
begin
  FCriticalSection.Leave;
end;
```

Usage

```
  Device.Lock;
  try
    Device.ms... // access it
  finally
    Device.Unlock;
  end;
```

And pass this whole Device anywhere you want, not just the stream.

**Then you can simplify the thread**

```
constructor TClientThread.Create(const Address:string;
  ADevice:TDevice);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
```

And also **handle exception in the execute**

```
procedure TClientThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    ... your code here ...
  except

  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why are you passing the lock arg by var?

Comment: Yes, no var. It's my mistake.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I see, you mean in that "simplify"? That was just copy&paste because of that CreateSuspended, sure it has to be removed.

Comment: **DavidHeffernan** and **smooty86**, thank You very much for your help and comments. BR, Konstantin